# signals or triggers in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

does SQLAlchemy have something similar to Django's signal concept? Basically, I'd like to trigger a few functions when I pre-save or post-save some entity objects. Thanks.

Edit: I JUST want equivalent of django-signals in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: What's wrong with simply overriding `save`?

Comment: @S.Lott Sorry to resurrect an ancient thread, but the SQLAlchemy declarative module doesn't have the same concept of a `save` method that can be overridden like the Django ORM.  To save objects in SA, you add them to a session and then flush the session. You *can* implement your own declarative base class and achieve the same effect, however.

Comment: @JoeHolloway: While helpful, it doesn't explain why the tag says Django and the title says SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 16):

I think you are looking for `ORM Events'.
You can find documentation here:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html

Comment: BTW, `MapperExtension` from other answers is [deprecated](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/deprecated.html) since SQLAlchemy 0.7. So 'ORM Events' looks like a proper solution.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't make clear, whether you are integrating SQLAlchemy and Django, or you JUST want equivalent of django-signals in SQLAlchemy.

If you want equivalent of Django signals like post_save, pre_save, pre_delete etc, i would refer you the page,

[sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/interfaces.html#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension)

Comment: See the answer from S.C. for "ORM Events" for the current way to do this.  From the SQLAlchemy docs: "New in version 0.7: The event supersedes the previous system of “extension” classes."

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider the [sqlalchemy.orm.SessionExtension](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/interfaces.html#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.SessionExtension) as well

Here's some code I threw together to set an owner id on an instance and set an update_date that get's the job done in a pylons app.  the OrmExt class is where all the magic happens. And init_model is where you wire it up.

```
import logging
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

from pylons import session

import datetime

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ORMSecurityException(Exception):
    '''
    thrown for security violations in orm layer
    '''
    pass

def _get_current_user():
    log.debug('getting current user from session...')
    log.debug(session)
    return session['user'] 

def _is_admin(user):
    return False  


def set_update_date(instance):

    if hasattr(instance,'update_date'):
    instance.update_date = datetime.datetime.now()

def set_owner(instance):
    '''
    if owner_id, run it through the rules
    '''
    log.info('set_owner')
    if hasattr(instance, 'owner_id'):
    log.info('instance.owner_id=%s' % instance.owner_id)
    u = _get_current_user()
    log.debug('user: %s' % u.email)
    if not u:
        #anonymous users can't save owned objects
        raise ORMSecurityException()
    if instance.owner_id==None:
        #must be new object thus, owned by current user
        log.info('setting owner on object %s for user: %s' % (instance.__class__.__name__,u.email))
        instance.owner_id = u.id
    elif instance.owner_id!=u.id and not _is_admin(u):
        #if owner_id does not match user_id and user is not admin VIOLATION
        raise ORMSecurityException()
    else:
        log.info('object is already owned by this user')
        return #good to go
else:
    log.info('%s is not an owned object' % instance.__class__.__name__)
    return

def instance_policy(instance):
    log.info('setting owner for %s' % instance.__class__.__name__)
    set_owner(instance)
    log.info('setting update_date for %s' % instance.__class__.__name__)
    set_update_date(instance)


class ORMExt(orm.SessionExtension):
    '''
    attempt at managing ownership logic on objects
    '''
    def __init__(self,policy):
        self._policy = policy

    def before_flush(self,sqlsess,flush_context,instances):
        '''
        check all instances for owner_id==user.id
        '''
        try:
            for instance in sqlsess.deleted:
                try:
                    log.info('running policy for deleted %s' % instance.__class__.__name__)
                    self._policy(instance)
                except Exception,ex:
                    log.error(ex)
                    raise ex

            for instance in sqlsess.new:
                try:
                    log.info('running policy for new %s' % instance.__class__.__name__)
                    self._policy(instance)
                except Exception,ex:
                    log.error(ex)
                    raise ex

            for instance in sqlsess.dirty:
                try:
                    if sqlsess.is_modified(instance,include_collections=False,passive=True):
                        log.info('running policy for updated %s' % instance.__class__.__name__)
                        self._policy(instance)
                except Exception, ex:
                    log.error(ex)
                    raise ex

        except Exception,ex:
            sqlsess.expunge_all()
            raise ex

def init_model(engine):
    """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model"""
    sm = orm.sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=True, bind=engine,extension=ORMExt(instance_policy))
    meta.engine = engine
    meta.Session = orm.scoped_session(sm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take at this problem, it uses [Louie](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Louie) to dispatch signals:

**`dispatch.py`**

```
"""
Signals dispatching for SQLAlchemy mappers.
"""

import louie
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import MapperExtension
import signals


class LouieDispatcherExtension(MapperExtension):
    """
    Dispatch signals using louie on insert, update and delete actions.
    """

    def after_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        louie.send(signals.after_insert, instance.__class__,
                instance=instance)
        return super(LouieDispatcherExtension, self).after_insert(mapper,
                connection, instance)

    def after_delete(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        louie.send(signals.after_delete, instance.__class__,
                instance=instance)
        return super(LouieDispatcherExtension, self).after_delete(mapper,
                connection, instance)

    def after_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        louie.send(signals.after_update, instance.__class__,
                instance=instance)
        return super(LouieDispatcherExtension, self).after_update(mapper,
                connection, instance)

    def before_delete(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        louie.send(signals.before_delete, instance.__class__,
                instance=instance)
        return super(LouieDispatcherExtension, self).before_delete(mapper,
                connection, instance)

    def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        louie.send(signals.before_insert, instance.__class__,
                instance=instance)
        return super(LouieDispatcherExtension, self).before_insert(mapper,
                connection, instance)

    def before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        louie.send(signals.before_update, instance.__class__,
                instance=instance)
        return super(LouieDispatcherExtension, self).before_update(mapper,
                connection, instance)
```

**`signals.py`**

```
from louie import Signal


class after_delete(Signal): pass
class after_insert(Signal): pass
class after_update(Signal): pass
class before_delete(Signal): pass
class before_insert(Signal): pass
class before_update(Signal): pass
```

Sample usage:

```
class MyModel(DeclarativeBase):

    __mapper_args__ = {"extension": LouieDispatcherExtension()}

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

def on_insert(instance):
    print "inserted %s" % instance

louie.connect(on_insert, signals.after_insert, MyModel)
```

Comment: There is one problem with all mentioned events, they are already in the middle of flush process. So while it's good enough to modify column on instance, it's not sufficient if you want make more complex actions like adding/removing instance from session. All those changes will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner `MapperExtension` class:

```
class YourModel(db.Model):

    class BaseExtension(MapperExtension):

        def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
            # do something here

        def before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
            # do something here

    __mapper_args__ = { 'extension': BaseExtension() }

    # ....
```

Comment: Can I use this for making a trigger that on insert, inserts a row in another table? Something like a table that acts as a log.